# Problem Connecting to SSL 1.2 Host from Java - Ignoring Unsupported Cipher Suite for TLS v1

Tags: ssl, java-8, tls1.2

I am connecting to a finicky host that uses SSL v1.2.

It seems to be failing to connect due to the appropriate cipher not being found.  I don't know why?

**Host Configuration**

Analyzing the host using immuniniweb.com shows it supports the following cipher suites (for TLSv1.2):

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

**Notes**

- The connection is using a certificate supplied by the host
- The connection works using *stunnel*
- The connection is for a non-HTTP protocol
- The Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files have been installed.

**Connecting**

However when I connect using java (`jdk1.8.0_65` on MacOS) with the following options:

```
   -Djavax.net.debug=SSL:handshake:verbose
   -Djavax.net.debug=all
   -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
   -Dhttps.cipherSuites=TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
   -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

I get the following results:

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring disabled protocol: SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1564124670 bytes = { 182, 166, 70, 240, 207, 103, 192, 255, 249, 156, 39, 115, 16, 135, 116, 22, 247, 138, 216, 231, 235, 150, 230, 254, 147, 191, 153, 156 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 237
0000: 01 00 00 E9 03 03 5D 3B   A6 FE B6 A6 46 F0 CF 67  ......];....F..g
0010: C0 FF F9 9C 27 73 10 87   74 16 F7 8A D8 E7 EB 96  ....'s..t.......
0020: E6 FE 93 BF 99 9C 00 00   64 C0 24 C0 28 00 3D C0  ........d.$.(.=.
0030: 26 C0 2A 00 6B 00 6A C0   0A C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0  &.*.k.j.....5...
0040: 0F 00 39 00 38 C0 23 C0   27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29 00  ..9.8.#.'.<.%.).
0050: 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13 00   2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33 00  g.@...../.....3.
0060: 32 C0 2C C0 2B C0 30 00   9D C0 2E C0 32 00 9F 00  2.,.+.0.....2...
0070: A3 C0 2F 00 9C C0 2D C0   31 00 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0  ../...-.1.......
0080: 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00   16 00 13 00 FF 01 00 00  ................
0090: 5C 00 0A 00 34 00 32 00   17 00 01 00 03 00 13 00  \...4.2.........
00A0: 15 00 06 00 07 00 09 00   0A 00 18 00 0B 00 0C 00  ................
00B0: 19 00 0D 00 0E 00 0F 00   10 00 11 00 02 00 12 00  ................
00C0: 04 00 05 00 14 00 08 00   16 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00  ................
00D0: 0D 00 1A 00 18 06 03 06   01 05 03 05 01 04 03 04  ................
00E0: 01 03 03 03 01 02 03 02   01 02 02 01 01           .............
NioProcessor-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 237
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 206
0000: 01 03 03 00 A5 00 00 00   20 00 C0 24 00 C0 28 00  ........ ..$..(.
0010: 00 3D 00 C0 26 00 C0 2A   00 00 6B 00 00 6A 00 C0  .=..&..*..k..j..
0020: 0A 07 00 C0 00 C0 14 00   00 35 00 C0 05 00 C0 0F  .........5......
0030: 00 00 39 00 00 38 00 C0   23 00 C0 27 00 00 3C 00  ..9..8..#..'..<.
0040: C0 25 00 C0 29 00 00 67   00 00 40 00 C0 09 06 00  .%..)..g..@.....
0050: 40 00 C0 13 00 00 2F 00   C0 04 01 00 80 00 C0 0E  @...../.........
0060: 00 00 33 00 00 32 00 C0   2C 00 C0 2B 00 C0 30 00  ..3..2..,..+..0.
0070: 00 9D 00 C0 2E 00 C0 32   00 00 9F 00 00 A3 00 C0  .......2........
0080: 2F 00 00 9C 00 C0 2D 00   C0 31 00 00 9E 00 00 A2  /.....-..1......
0090: 00 C0 08 00 C0 12 00 00   0A 07 00 C0 00 C0 03 02  ................
00A0: 00 80 00 C0 0D 00 00 16   00 00 13 00 00 FF 5D 3B  ..............];
00B0: A6 FE B6 A6 46 F0 CF 67   C0 FF F9 9C 27 73 10 87  ....F..g....'s..
00C0: 74 16 F7 8A D8 E7 EB 96   E6 FE 93 BF 99 9C        t.............
NioProcessor-2, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 206
[Raw write]: length = 208
0000: 80 CE 01 03 03 00 A5 00   00 00 20 00 C0 24 00 C0  .......... ..$..
0010: 28 00 00 3D 00 C0 26 00   C0 2A 00 00 6B 00 00 6A  (..=..&..*..k..j
0020: 00 C0 0A 07 00 C0 00 C0   14 00 00 35 00 C0 05 00  ...........5....
0030: C0 0F 00 00 39 00 00 38   00 C0 23 00 C0 27 00 00  ....9..8..#..'..
0040: 3C 00 C0 25 00 C0 29 00   00 67 00 00 40 00 C0 09  <..%..)..g..@...
0050: 06 00 40 00 C0 13 00 00   2F 00 C0 04 01 00 80 00  ..@...../.......
0060: C0 0E 00 00 33 00 00 32   00 C0 2C 00 C0 2B 00 C0  ....3..2..,..+..
0070: 30 00 00 9D 00 C0 2E 00   C0 32 00 00 9F 00 00 A3  0........2......
0080: 00 C0 2F 00 00 9C 00 C0   2D 00 C0 31 00 00 9E 00  ../.....-..1....
0090: 00 A2 00 C0 08 00 C0 12   00 00 0A 07 00 C0 00 C0  ................
00A0: 03 02 00 80 00 C0 0D 00   00 16 00 00 13 00 00 FF  ................
00B0: 5D 3B A6 FE B6 A6 46 F0   CF 67 C0 FF F9 9C 27 73  ];....F..g....'s
00C0: 10 87 74 16 F7 8A D8 E7   EB 96 E6 FE 93 BF 99 9C  ..t.............
NioProcessor-2, called closeOutbound()
NioProcessor-2, closeOutboundInternal()
NioProcessor-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
NioProcessor-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 01 00                               .......
NioProcessor-2, called closeInbound()
NioProcessor-2, fatal error: 80: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
NioProcessor-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
NioProcessor-2, Exception sending alert: java.io.IOException: writer side was already closed.
NioProcessor-2, called closeOutbound()
NioProcessor-2, closeOutboundInternal()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove `SSLv2Hello` from the list of enabled protocols. This has nothing to do with cipher suites. There's not much point in setting `https.*` properties if you aren't using HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the problem is simply that the `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2` option is not making its way through to the third party library that is creating the SSL connection.

Running a simple piece of code to perform the connection with that option works.

The giveaway was @user207421 's comment that SSLv2Hello seemed to be enabled - the documentation states that if you specify TSLv1.2 then SSLv2Hello is disabled already.